# Return top 5 items with LISTAGG in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am able to get a comma list of all used images in a single field with this typical LISTAGG code:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(IMAGE, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY IMAGE ASC) AS IMAGES 
FROM   STATUS 
WHERE  DRIVER_CODE='AZUSE2'
```

However, that brings back every image ever used for the driver. What I want is to only bring back the last 5 images, sorted by CREATED_ON DESC.  I'm new to DB2 and just started looking at options. What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(LISTAGG(IMAGE, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY IMAGE ASC), '') AS IMAGES 
FROM
(
SELECT *
FROM STATUS
WHERE DRIVER_CODE='AZUSE2'
ORDER BY CREATED_ON DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(CASE WHEN seqnum <=5 THEN IMAGE END, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY IMAGE ASC)  AS IMAGES 
FROM (SELECT s.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DRIVER_CODE ORDER BY CREATED_ON DESC) as seqnum
      FROM STATUS s
      ) s
WHERE DRIVER_CODE='AZUSE2'
GROUP BY DRIVER_CODE
```

Comment: One issue, how do I make sure it always returns, at least an empty string, if no images found for the driver.

Comment: It's better to edit your question with sample data and the result desired. Especially with absence of images for driver. What is image absence? Is this `IMAGE` column with `NULL`?